# How to get the mathematical expression of a trained network?

Tags: neural-networks

When a network is trained, is it possible to get the corresponding mathematical expression?

For instance consider this simple network:

```
data = {{-2., -2., -10.} -> {-2.2, -2.3}, {-2., -2., -9.5} -> {-2.2, -2.4}, {-2., -1., -9.} -> {-4., -1.23}}
net = NetChain[{2, LogisticSigmoid, 2, LogisticSigmoid, 2}, "Input" -> 3];
trained = NetTrain[net, data]
```

I would like to get an explicit definition of `f` such that `f[{x,y,z}] == trained[{x,y,z}]` for any values of `x,y,z`. Note: `trained[{x,y,z}]` only evaluates if the variables have values.

Comment: What do you mean by "an explicit definition of `f` "?

Comment: @user64494 Something like `f[{x_,y_,z_}] = {2x + 3z^2, 5.2y^3}` or more realistically `f[{x_,y_,z_}] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}.LogisticSigmoid[{x,y,z}] + ...` Like a closed-form expression.

Comment: Are `Piecewise`s allowed?The results of `trained[{5, -4000, 30}]` and `trained[{10, 10^7, 100}]` demonstrate that the dependance on `x,y,z` is very weak.

Comment: @user64494 I guess `Piecewise`s would appear with ReLU activation functions, for instance. Not sure where there would come from here. As per the weak dependence in `x,y,z`, it is only the case in the simplistic toy example (with arbitrary values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two similar questions on this topic ([#197422](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197422/can-i-extract-symbolic-expression-of-neural-network-loss-function), [#199360](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199360/finding-the-symbolic-expression-for-the-loss-function-of-a-basic-feed-forward-ne?noredirect=1&lq=1)), none of which has an answer. Neural networks in Mathematica are implemented via external library, called [MXNet](https://mxnet.apache.org). Using `Trace[trained[{1,2,3}]]`, you can see that the input is numerically transferred to MXNet, which evaluates the function.

For simple networks, you can get the symbolic function by extracting the relevant information from `NetChain`. The following code handles only `LinearLayer` and `ElementwiseLayer` but can probably be adapted for other types of layers.

```
netApply[input_, layer_] := Switch[NetExtract[layer, "Type"],
   ElementwiseLayer, NetExtract[layer, "Function"]@input,
   LinearLayer, Normal[NetExtract[layer, "Weights"]] . input + 
    Normal[NetExtract[layer, "Biases"]]
   ];

symbolicNet[net_NetChain] := 
  Function[Evaluate@
    FunctionExpand@
     Fold[netApply, Slot /@ Range@NetExtract[trained, "Input"], 
      NetExtract[net, All]]];

f = symbolicNet[trained]
```

> `{-1.07891 - 1.28238/(1 + E^(-0.945874 - 0.183235/( 1 + E^(0.14805 - 0.903133 #1 - 2.16383 #2 + 0.280905 #3)) - 1.79141/( 1 + E^(-0.0879924 + 1.29072 #1 - 0.38487 #2 + 1.21005 #3)))) - 0.672629/(1 + E^(-0.735348 + 0.915794/( 1 + E^(0.14805 - 0.903133 #1 - 2.16383 #2 + 0.280905 #3)) - 0.477314/( 1 + E^(-0.0879924 + 1.29072 #1 - 0.38487 #2 + 1.21005 #3)))), -0.309332 - 0.897976/(1 + E^(-0.945874 - 0.183235/( 1 + E^(0.14805 - 0.903133 #1 - 2.16383 #2 + 0.280905 #3)) - 1.79141/( 1 + E^(-0.0879924 + 1.29072 #1 - 0.38487 #2 + 1.21005 #3)))) - 1.08833/(1 + E^(-0.735348 + 0.915794/( 1 + E^(0.14805 - 0.903133 #1 - 2.16383 #2 + 0.280905 #3)) - 0.477314/( 1 + E^(-0.0879924 + 1.29072 #1 - 0.38487 #2 + 1.21005 #3))))} &`

Validating the function:

```
f[1, 2, 3] - trained[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> `{-1.33618*10^-7, 8.15666*10^-8}`

Comment: I confirm that Domen answered exactly my question, and I also have differences in the order of $10^{-7}$.

"Using Trace[trained[{1,2,3}]], you can see that the input is numerically transferred to MXNet" -> how do you read that in the output? I get essentially things like `NeuralNetworks`Private`NetApply`. Thank you by the way!

Comment: @anderstood, click on _show all_, then you can see expressions like ``MXNetLink`MXExecutorForward[...]`` ...